# CodeIgniter-Checking session variable is already set or not when clicking each link or reloading page

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a controller named admin,and all functions in the controller can be used if the session variable is set,so what are the best ways to check if the session is set ,when clicking each link in the page or reloading the pages...

> for example: if i open my admin home page in multiple tabs in a
>   browser and sign off from first tab, bt after that in the second tab
>   all links a working properly

so i want to check if the session is set or not...

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to check whether the session variable is set or not, then use this.

```
if($this->session->userdata('session_variable')) {

      // Do your code here
}
```

Meanwhile, if you want to check whether the session variable is set with a particular value, then you can use this.

```
if($this->session->userdata('session_variable') == "VALUE") {

      // Do your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help,but in my controller there are many functions like add_user,delete_user and edit _user etc,so how can i check session automatically in all of these functions

Comment: You can define this in constructor.. Constructor will be the first one which is loaded when a controller being accessed.

Comment: Another way to do this if you have multiple controllers is to extend the CI base controller with MY_Controller and do the check there. All your controllers would then extend MY_Controller. Doing it in the constructor is fine if you only have a couple of controllers, once that number starts growing you're better off extending the base controller  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Good but what id the session data is to be set to true or false

Answer (score 1):

According to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html 
"Retrieving Session Data",

```
$this->session->userdata('not_set')
```

returns false.

Answer (score -9):

Simple join query solve your issue.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('first_table_name ftn');
$this->db->join('second_table_name stn', 'ftn.id = stn.id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```